# Can I "retroactively" add class methods from a module (after it's already been included)?

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming, class-method

In Ruby, I can do this:

```
module Foo
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

module Foo
  def do_something_instancey
    puts "I'm an instance!"
  end
end
```

Then, if I instantiate a `Bar` object, I can call `do_something_instancey` on it:

```
b = Bar.new
b.do_something_instancey
```

However, if I do this...

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    def base.do_something_classy do
      puts "I'm a class!"
    end
  end
end
```

My understanding is that because I included `Foo` in `Bar` *before* defining that class method, I cannot call `Bar.do_something_classy` because it never got "attached" to `Bar`.

I realize that might be slightly inaccurate/not really the right terminology. Regardless, is there a way, in the above example, to attach a class method to `Bar` from `Foo` after the module has already been included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example for both, class and instance methods:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

   module ClassMethods
   end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

module Foo
  def do_something_instancey
    puts "I'm an instance!"
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def do_something_classy
      puts "I'm a class!"
    end
  end
end

b = Bar.new
b.do_something_instancey
# => I'm an instance!
Bar.do_something_classy
# => I'm a class!
```

---

To add class methods to each class that has (already) included a specific module, you could traverse Ruby's [`ObjectSpace`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html):

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) do |klass|
  if klass.include? Foo
    klass.define_singleton_method(:do_something_classy) do
      puts "I'm a class!"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a good start. However it still requires the `base.extend(ClassMethods)` part to take place before `Foo` is included in `Bar`. Can you think of any way to do this *without* such a requirement?

Comment: Why do you have to avoid `extend`?

Comment: It isn't that I have to avoid `extend` (or that I *have* to do anything, for that matter—I asked this question mostly to educate myself). Rather, I'm looking for an approach that can solve the problem entirely *retroactively*. In other words, I'm trying to figure out if this scenario is possible: I take your library, comprising a bunch of classes and modules that I'm not allowed to modify. Now I want to re-open one of your modules in *my* library such that I can also add class methods to the classes that have already included that module. Make sense?

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about the `ObjectSpace` module—I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Description of [retroactive_module_inclusion](http://rubygems.org/gems/retroactive_module_inclusion) gem:

> This gem circumvents the "dynamic module include" (aka "double
>   inclusion") problem, which is the fact that M.module_eval { include N
>   } does not make the methods of module N available to modules and
>   classes which had included module M beforehand, only to the ones that
>   include it thereafter. This behaviour hurts the least surprise
>   principle, specially because if K is a class, then K.class_eval {
>   include M } *does* make all methods of M available to all classes
>   which had previously inherited it.